# TeXstudio has no commands

Tags: miktex, texstudio

Unfortunately I had to reinstall my Windows and I installed MiKTeX using the 64 bit installer and everything went fine including running TeXworks and compiling something (so I assume everything is installed correctly).

But, no matter which editor I try (and I tried several) none of them pick up where the MiKTeX is installed and because of that they can't compile anything. Here's how my TeXstudio looks:

[image]

I have no idea what I did wrong since I tried reinstalling MiKTeX several times.

Comment: Can the relevant binaries be found in your system's PATH? Try opening cmd.exe and typing `pdflatex --version` or something similar. Do you get any output?

Comment: I get the following output:
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.5496 (1.40.15) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2014 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.

So I assume it works!

Comment: you can't do this your self by hand? I think you didnt do enything wrong but texwork is associted with miktex and texstudio not.

Comment: I am not an experienced user and I don't want to enter and commands that are not correct. The problem is that I always installed it like this and TeXstudio always picked up the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first startup (or to be more precise, when there is no settings file yet), TXS tries to detect existing LaTeX installations.

If you started TXS without having a LaTeX installation, the commands will be empty. You can repeat the detection by [restoring to the default settings](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-can-i-restore-the-default-settings).

If that doesn't work, here is a screenshot of the default command configuration:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I already took care of it by doing the last thing myself so it's working now!

Comment: +1. This kind of issue seems to be decently common, i.e. users installing TeXstudio before a TeX distribution. Would it be possible to implement something like a test so that if all the *TeX engines are `<unknown>` at startup, TeXstudio asks if it should do the detection again?